# Disable screen capture in windows forms desktop applications using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, desktop, capture

I am developing a windows desktop application in C# and I want to disable screen captures of this application. 
Can I get suggestions for this?

Comment: As mentioned, don't try this.  Use a work around or communicate to business folks that it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Airbone for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only attempt to scramble whatever gets captured, as discussed here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263112/detect-or-prevent-screen-capture-applications

Comment: Thanks Kristaps currently we have removed the screen capture blocking requirement and thanks for the help